# UITableViewCell dynamic height server-side

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, height, server-side

I have some problems getting `heights` of my `cells` because I have dynamic `height` `images` inside them and while using some `async` methods (`AFNetworking`) it still looks bad when `cells` dynamically change because `UITableView` `offset` is constantly changing.

While looking in `facebook`, `9gag` or some other apps I saw that they have set their `post` (`cell`) `height` before `image` is loaded (so with some placeholder) but that `height` perfectly fits `image` that comes in so I was wondering hows that possible (since if theres no image you cant tell its height yet).

Would it be a good approach to determine `image` `height` on `server` and send that to iOS app along with `imageURL`, `title` and other stuff I have in `cell` and then determine `cell` `height` based on that?

Or any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image they are loading probably comes from an rss or html feed where they list the width and height of the image in the html.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

If you can parse something like this or have your server return the height and width from a database table then you should be able to generate a placeholder image.

Answer (score 1):

What likely happens is what Greg said. Data (JSON or XML etc) is returned from a feed that contains the title of post, image size, and the URL for the image. The app will then async load the image whilst a placeholder is in the cell constructed with the details returned from the feed.